# submenus in php using json

Tags: php, json

```
<?php 
    $jsondata = file_get_contents('js/brand.json');
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    $menuonesublinks = $data['menuonesublinks']['links'];
    foreach ($menuonesublinks as $menu_sublink) {
        ?>
        <?php  
            echo $menu_sublink['title'];
        ?>
        <?php 
    }
?>
```

o/p i am getting : `usa,uk`

how can i get inside subcities of city values `("subcities":[{"city":"dubai"},{'city':"london"}])`

**brand.json**

```
{
    "menuonesublinks": {
        "links": [
            {
                "title": "usa",
                "subcities":[{"city":"dubai"},{'city':"london"}]
            },
            {
                "title": uk
            }   
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `foreach` loop in the following way,

```
// your code
foreach ($menuonesublinks as $menu_sublink) {
    echo $menu_sublink['title']; 
    if(array_key_exists('subcities', $menu_sublink)){
        foreach($menu_sublink['subcities'] as $subcity){
            // Now access subcities like this: $subcity['city']
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the relevant reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php